# Is there a way to specify trusted origins for post requests in google web app?

Tags: http, security, google-apps-script, http-post, google-sheets-api

Let's say i created a google sheet to capture user's email addresses. 
On my website there is a small form and once the submit button is clicked and an ajax request to a google web app that writes data to a sheet is fired:

```
// Let's select and cache all the fields
var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");

// Serialize the data in the form
var serializedData = $form.serialize();

// Fire off the request
request = $.ajax({
    url: https://script.google.com/macros/s/longURLcode/exec,
    type: "post",
    data: serializedData
});
```

In the google script you now use doPost(e) or doGet(e) to handle any incoming http request. To allow this to work as a sign up mechanism permissions for the web app have to be set to (i think !?)

*Execute the app as*: Me (myemail@gmail.com)

*Who has access to the app:* Anyone, even anonymous

Given everything on the google script site is set up properly, this works like a charm. So whats wrong?

**Problem:**

Anyone can either look into the source code of my webpage or use the dev tools to extract the url to the google web app after clicking submit. This url can now in theory be used to flood the sheet with countless (undefined) entries.

**Questions:**

1) Is there a way to limit accepted http request to certain origins? I tried to do this by accessing the http headers within doPost() but there seems to be no way to do so.

2) Is "*Who has access to the app:* Anyone, even anonymous" the wrong approach? I thought this is necessary since you can only choose google users here and some url (mywebsite.com) seemed to fall within the anonymous category.

3) I don't think this is possible but maybe i missed an option: Is there a way to NOT expose the google web app url to anyone? I guess not because you can monitor any requests with dev tools.

4) Is using sheets for capturing that kind of data just a terrible idea in general (partly for above reasons) and i should find another solution asap?

Comment: You could try putting an Apps Script web app into an <iframe> in your website.  The Apps Script web app will make a call to the server with `google.script.run.myScriptFunctionName(data)`  That way, they won't see the spreadsheet URL.  You can remove the AJAX code from your website.  The published URL of the web app goes into the iframe tag.  The web app html will load automatically when your website load.  Put the small form that is now in your website into the apps script web app.  You will get a message saying, 'This was not created by Google' from the web app.

Comment: You can fill out an application form to prove that you are the owner of the web app.  I think that gets rid of that annoying message.  I'm not 100% sure, but I think so.

Comment: You can replace your existing form with a Google Form and link that Google Form to your Google Sheet. You can then provide a link to the form on your site. The form can also be embedded into a Google Site.

Comment: Thank you  @SandyGood , i will try that out once i find some time.

Comment: Thank you @DimuDesigns, i will look into that, but my fear would be that swapping a form with a link impacts the user experience too much.